# operand must be relocatable Assembly x86 problem

Tags: assembly, irvine32

In this code, I am trying to access the array[i-1][j+1] and in assembly, we can only handle 1D arrays so I am trying to access this index by subtracting the current index from my width "W" and multiply it by 4 because the type is DWORD
but when I try this line "MOV EAX, [EDI - P]" it results in an error any hints?

```
        MOV EAX, W
        ADD EAX, 1
        MOV EBX, 4
        MUL EBX
        MOV P, EAX
        MOV EAX, [EDI- p];; up Right
        ADD ESI, EAX
```

Comment: What registers contain i and j?

Comment: there are no registers containing  i , j I am accessing via width

Comment: The computation for the byte offset into the array is: (W * (i - 1) + (j + 1)) * 4

Comment: How can you access array[i-1][j+1] without i and j?

Comment: assume that you have array of  width = 5 and you are on index 7
and you want to access arr[i-1][j] then
Current index - Width  = arr[i-1][j]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your attempt: You cannot subtract in an addressing mode, and you cannot use the contents of a memory location.

However, you can add a constant and you can multiply by 2, 4, or 8, both of which can be used to advantage here.

```
        MOV EAX, W
        NEG EAX
        MOV EAX, 4[EDI+EAX*4];; up Right
        ADD ESI, EAX
```

The constant can be negative, so when you want to access array[i-1][j-1], you can use

```
        MOV EAX, -4[EDI+EAX*4];; up left
```

Comment: You can add a negative number in an addressing mode.  The issue is that object-file formats don't support a relocation type that negates the absolute address, so there's no way to get the linker to fill in the right disp32 for `[esi - P]`.  There is a plausible use-case: `LEA eax, [esi - P]` as a size calculation.  But yeah, it looks like the OP thought there'd be an extra level of indirection.